# Calculate power of all the numbers till n-1

Tags: c

Given n, the program should calculate 1^1 + 2^2 + 3^3 + ... till n-1^n-1. Below is my code, in which there is one function inside while loop which and the passed value is from n-1 in the function. The function definition has two variables which return the ans. Output is wrong always 1.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int power(int x, int y)
{
    int la, ans;
    if(y==0)
        return 1;
    else
        la= (x*power(x, y-1));  
        ans+=la;
        return ans;
}
int main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    while(t--)
    {
        int n, m, a, b, res, res1;
        scanf("%d%d", &n, &m);
        while(n-- && n>0)
        {
            a = power(n-1, n-1);
        }
        printf("%d", a);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your output? Why is it wrong?

Comment: gcc says `warning: ‘ans’ may be used uninitialized in this function`

Comment: Output is always `1`

Answer (score 1):

Some problems in your code.

1. As pointed in another answer, your `power` function was broken:

   - `ans` was not initialized
   - `{` `}` were missing after the `else`
2. in the `while`, you compute `x^x`, but you forget the result, whearas you
   should sum it.
3. first thing you do in `while` loop is to decrease `n` and to compute `power(n-1, n-1)`
   that sound not logical.

Hence, your corrected code could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int power(int x, int y)
{
    if(y==0)
        return 1;
    else
        return x*power(x, y-1);  
}
int main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    while(t--)
    {
        int n, m, b, a = 0;
        scanf("%d%d", &n, &m);
        while(n>1)
        {
            --n;
            b = power(n, n);
            a += b;
            printf("%d^%d -> %3d\n",n, n, b);                
        }
        printf("sum= %d", a);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Gives for n = 6:

```
5^5 -> 3125
4^4 -> 256
3^3 ->  27
2^2 ->   4
1^1 ->   1
sum=3413
```

Comment: What does that mean `ans` was not initialized

Comment: When you type "`int ans;`", you create a *variable* which *initial* value can be anything, if you type "`int ans = 0;`", you create a *variable* with *inital* value set to `0`.

Comment: When you write `ans += 1;`, if the initial value of `ans` is anything, the result will be anything too. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1597405/1212012)

Answer (score 0):

C uses braces to form blocks, your `power()` function looks like it's wanting to use indentation like in Python.

It should probably be:

```
int power(int x, int y)
{
    int la, ans;
    if(y==0)
        return 1;
    else
    {
        la= (x*power(x, y-1));  
        ans+=la;
        return ans;
    }
}
```

Of course since the first `if` has a `return`, the `else` is pointless, and you can simplify the code:

```
int power(int x, int y)
{
    if (y==0)
        return 1;
    return x * power(x, y-1);
}
```

The variable `ans` was never assigned to, that looked broken so I simplified it out.

Of course this is susceptible to integer overflow.

Comment: but that won't calculate the sum of 1^1 + 2^2 + 3^3 + ... till n-1^n-1, I want output as a complete sum of **1^1 + 2^2 + 3^3 + ... till n-1^n-1**

Comment: @hemantvikaspatnaik No, my understanding was that `power()` should just compute integer exponentiation, and then you should have a loop elsewhere to do the summing.